# Geometry of triangle

Tags: geometry

I'm working out this problem. 
I've attempted different approaches and I find that these relations may be helpful :
AC = (1+x)AY
AB = (1+x)BZ
BC = (1+x)CX

The main problem is that I don't know how to compute the area of a triangle without using the base height formula.

Anyone's idea ?[image]

Comment: Is that third fraction supposed to be $\frac{BZ}{ZA}$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, that is what i took it to be. the figure seems to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

let $t = \dfrac{1}{1+x}, s = 1-t = \dfrac{x}{1+x}, a= BC, b = CA, c = AB.$  then $CX = at, XB = sa, BZ = tc, ZA = sc, AY = tb, YC = xb$  we use the formula that twice area of a triangle is the product of two arms and the $\sin$ of the angle between them.

the sum of the areas of $$AYZ + CXY + BXZ = \frac{1}{2}st\left(bc\sin A + ab\sin C + ac\sin b\right)= 3stABC= 3st = \dfrac{3x}{(1+x)^2}$$

therefore the area of $$XYZ = 1 - \frac{3x}{(1+x)^2} = \dfrac{1-x+x^2}{(1+x)^2}$$

Comment: I must admit that I have to read this all over again more than twice to understand the reasoning. Thank you. I've just downloaded a Advanced High School Mathematics lecture notes and I didn't think it was so hard to solve geometry problems.

Comment: Just a question : what are a, b and c ?

Comment: @abel: Nice and simple result! Just wondered if we take x = 4/3 = YC/YA, does XYZ vanish? What may be the physical interpretation? Do I miss something?

Comment: @Narasimham, thanks for your check. i made several careless errors. i hope there are no more errors.

Comment: @user3061105, i made some careless errors. they are corrected now. hopefully no more remains.

Comment: @abel, mine was wrong on basis of similitude,deleted it.

Comment: @Narasimham, you can see that answer must be invariant if we replace $x$ by $1/x.$